# Handling hidden input on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How would you tackle the following problem, using Google Sheets:
User A and B bot need to submit an input (some text) to a shared sheet. The input must be hidden from the other user until both have submitted. Both users can change the input until the reveal, but not afterwards. Think of it as simultaneous action selection, except it's on different time zones so we can't just shout one two three go.

Currently, we are using salted hashes. That is inefficient and time consuming. I'd like to automate it. However, I don't know of any tool inside Google Sheets that allows you to hide inputs from other users under certain conditions, or anything that locks the input after both submit either (the submission shouldn't be tampered with unless both users agree, unless it's done before the other user submits).

This might need to be done with external coding, and I'm up to that (although I currently have no idea how to integrate it in google sheets). However I have never programmed something that read input from anything other than a terminal (or a txt file that one time it was required in class) so please provide some reference for that too. :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Umm, pardon my ignorance but what does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: I didn't want to put no tags, it somehow seemed wrong to me? And Excel and Google Sheets are similar enough I thought it would sort of fit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Google Form as the input tool. Then after both users have sent the input, share the spreadsheet with them. This could be done manually or with Google Apps Script.

**References**
[Create a survey using Google Forms - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/87809?hl=en)
[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)